# How to start earning at an early age (in your teens)?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, india, canada

With lots of business opportunities coming up in the market, what would be the best one to adopt in order to earn some quick and safe money?

Comment: How early is "early"?

Comment: What's your current socio-economic level?

Comment: Urban or rural?

Comment: What's the economy like where you live?

Comment: What are your interests?

Comment: @RonJohn pls refer edits. Urban. In India economy still seems to be growing (which is in fact good). My interests are anything starting from selling things (not actually as a salesman) to setting up an empire by doing things which are consumer demands in the current market scenario.

Comment: Any explanations why too broad?!

Comment: It's too broad because the only answer is, "find a job, work hard, and don't spend more than you earn (i.e. go in debt)".

Comment: Well there are many other things to do other than getting a “job “

Comment: If there was a quick and safe way of making money, which didn't involve going to work, then everybody would be doing it.

Comment: @user377340 putting it on hold gives you or someone else an opportunity to edit it into a format that's suitable for the site. If you're interested in asking a good question and getting good answers, take a look around the site for highly voted questions, and read the help center: https://money.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Thanks @GaneshSittampalam I’ll try to put in more of details. Even your cooperation is required.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, when earning money, "quick" and "safe" are often mutually contradictory. If you observe some kind of quick opportunity in the market (say, an arbitrage), these kinds of opportunities have a tendency to go away quite soon.

So I would focus more on the "safe" part, ignoring the "quick". Try to obtain a good education that guarantees a job in a reasonable timeframe. Don't forget to obtain job experience in your field at the same time by working as a trainee.

Then live cheaply and invest in stocks at an early age when you start earning. A well diversified stock portfolio is guaranteed to return well in a 40-year timeframe. So, when young, I would put 100% of investable assets in stocks (apart from a small emergency fund).

Consider carefully whether you want to rent or buy a house. Take into account the fact that by renting a house, you may be able to put more money into your stock portfolio. Don't ignore this "more stocks" effect as it may mean renting in some cases may be better than buying a house. But this depends so much on the local market situation that I cannot say one to be better than the other always.

Comment: "A well diversified stock portfolio is guaranteed to return well in a 40-year timeframe." This sentence ruins your answer.

Comment: @Hart CO seems to be correct. Going forward with an investment which in your case seems a long term invst. is actually not what the current growing scenario demands and would be a patience kind of a thing. Though I do agree with some of your points.

Comment: I used to have a similar opinion, but I've found in most of the places I've lived, it would cost roughly the same (Before factoring downpayment of course) for me to pay a mortgage vs renting. If I were to get a 15 year loan, half of my payments would be amortized as principal, thus building assets equal to half of my rent payment. It would be *hard* to make up that opportunity cost of building those early assets / equity on the home if he rented instead and went to stocks, though not impossible.